# How to compile a gemfile. I have the source contents of a gem called m_t_parser, it wouldn't compile but it left me the source files

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a gem called m_t_parser, or rather a FORM of the gem.  I tried to install it from a different source and it downloaded it but it downloaded it in what looks to be more of a source format.  This looks like something perhaps the devkit would normally compile?  This is something I haven't done before.  How would I go about assembling this gem into something useable?

This gem isn't available on Rubygems or any "normal" repository and I need it to finish a re-write of an older version of a Rails v3.2 app into the current version v6.1.4.1

Here is a list of the files themselves if this helps in any way.

```
C:\Ruby27-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.7.0\gems\m_t_parser-1.1.7\ext\src>dir
 Volume in drive C is BOOT_OS_SSD_0001
 Volume Serial Number is 06D2-9540

 Directory of C:\Ruby27-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.7.0\gems\m_t_parser-1.1.7\ext\src

11/24/2021  01:09 PM    <DIR>          .
11/24/2021  01:09 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               475 config.h
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,988 datalog.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             2,386 datalog.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             2,703 datalog_data_parser.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,267 datalog_data_parser.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM            16,085 datalog_parser.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             5,353 datalog_parser.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,295 datalog_parser_factory.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,189 datalog_parser_factory.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM            14,708 datalog_parser_worker.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             3,546 datalog_parser_worker.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               628 datalog_v2_data_parser.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               634 datalog_v2_data_parser.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             3,110 datalog_v2_parser.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               933 datalog_v2_parser.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               909 datalog_v2_validator.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               579 datalog_v2_validator.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               652 datalog_v4_data_parser.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               678 datalog_v4_data_parser.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             3,116 datalog_v4_parser.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               946 datalog_v4_parser.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,166 datalog_v4_validator.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               639 datalog_v4_validator.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             3,268 datalog_validator.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,217 datalog_validator.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM                90 extconf.h
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,025 extconf.rb
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               181 global_timer.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               377 global_timer.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             6,596 ioapi.c
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             6,837 ioapi.h
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               603 macro.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               233 mtparser_exception.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               254 mtparser_exception.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM            23,801 ruby_mtparser.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             2,844 ruby_mtparser.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             6,696 sql_record_formatter.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             2,750 sql_record_formatter.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               848 thread.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               754 thread.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,387 timer.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               498 timer.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM            71,086 unzip.c
11/24/2021  01:09 PM            16,358 unzip.h
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             2,141 util.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               560 util.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             3,209 xlsx_file.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             2,581 xlsx_file.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,322 xlsx_row_parser.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,232 xlsx_row_parser.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM            11,095 xlsx_sax_parser.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             2,776 xlsx_sax_parser.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             5,148 xlsx_shared_strings.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,830 xlsx_shared_strings.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             5,771 xml_sax_parser.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             6,351 xml_sax_parser.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM            11,414 zip.h
11/24/2021  01:09 PM               994 zipconf.h
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,390 zip_file.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             3,182 zip_file.hpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             8,369 zip_file_impl.cpp
11/24/2021  01:09 PM             1,958 zip_file_impl.hpp
```

I also figured out how to access the gemfury repository (it was an addon from Heroku) and on that repository I was able to download the m_t_parser-1.1.7.gem file. but even trying to install it with the --local flag is giving me the same issue, it expands the gem file into all of the files listed above and doesn't actually BUILD IT.  I read in the code it has a few requires which I downloaded the gems for (I believe at least) but still it will not build.

I managed to locate the compiled gem for this on gemfury however it still will not install, the first error I got was in a file called extconf.rb and it was uninitialized constant error CONFIG, had to change it to RbCONFIG and that fixed that part (I fixed it in the gem archive itself) then it would try to install, but now it is getting errors at different places in the C++ code which I am trying to address 1 at a time and have gone though about 10 of them so far but I keep running into them.  It appears this code was intended to be compiled on a Linux machine best I can tell so I know some of the errors are due to that.

Here is what is in the extconf.rb file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rbconfig'
require 'mkmf'

ext_name = 'm_t_parser'

optimize_level = '-O2'

$CXXFLAGS ||= ''

if defined?(CFLAGS)
  if CFLAGS.index(CONFIG['CCDLFLAGS'])
    $CFLAGS = CFLAGS + ' ' + CONFIG['CCDLFLAGS']
  else
    $CFLAGS = CFLAGS
  end
else
  $CFLAGS = CONFIG['CFLAGS']
end

$CFLAGS += " #{optimize_level} -g"
$CXXFLAGS += " #{optimize_level} -g"

$LDFLAGS = CONFIG['LDFLAGS']
$LIBPATH.push(RbConfig::CONFIG['libdir'])

def crash(str)
  printf(" extconf failure: %s\n", str)
  exit 1
end

dir_config(ext_name)

unless have_library('z', 'inflate') or
       have_library('zlib', 'inflate') or
       have_library('zlib1', 'inflate') or
       have_library('libz', 'inflate')
  crash('need zlib')
else
  $defs.push('-DHAVE_ZLIB_H')
end

unless have_library('pthread', 'pthread_create') 
  crash('need pthread')
else
  $defs.push('-DHAVE_PTHREAD_H')
end

# For FreeBSD add /usr/local/include
$INCFLAGS << " -I/usr/local/include"

$CFLAGS << ' ' << $INCFLAGS

create_header()
create_makefile(ext_name)
```

UPDATE:
I got the extconf.rb to run and it created the makefile.  I do not know the process to now use the makefile to compile the files into a GEM, I have been looking and looking and there is a lot out there on how to make a basic gem but not finding much on how to compile the files into a Ruby runnable .so file.

If anyone who has experience with this can give me some pointers or suggestions it would be appreciated.  I fixed and got the extconf.rb to run and it generated a makefile which looks like an instruction file on how to compile the gem but I don't know the next step in the process.

Do I need to install a specific Ruby gem to be able to run the makefile to create the gem? or?

Thank You,
Scott

Comment: What files are listed for the "m_t_parser-1.1.7" directory? (without ext/src) It is not uncommon for gems to have this type of directory structure for extensions, which in this case appear to be C++ but the ruby portion is likely in the root and the lib directories.

Comment: There is only 2 entries, one is the ext folder the other is a LICENSE file and that is it, if you go into the ext folder then there is a src folder and under that folder is that list of files.  I found out how to access the gemfury and I downloaded the m_t_parser-1.1.7 gem itself and so i tried to install it from local and it has been giving me errors in the files themselves which are apparently c++ files.  Fortunately I learned Java before Ruby so I understand most of the code I am reading and I have been editing the individual files that are erroring out from inside the archive.

Comment: This gem apparently wasn't Windows friendly at all so I have been having to fix/change some of the code and it has been taking quite some time, I have gotten past about 10 different errors now but every time I fix one another one comes up and I am just working them one at a time.  I am also trying to learn how to create gems from scratch as well so I can understand the process better.  Not sure what I am going to do because even if I get it to work on my Windows machine, will it them work on the Linux Heroku deployment, so I might end up having to make 2 versions of this gem.

Comment: I wish there was some way I could view the code for the compiled gem on the running Heroku instance, does anyone know if that is possible?  I tried to find the folder that contains the gems on Heroku and I couldn't find it, but I am not that good with Linux at all.  If I could read the ending Ruby code I could just integrate the gem directly or re-make it.

Comment: @engineersmnky Is there a way to use the Linux compiler for these files to turn it into a gem on a Windows Machine?  I don't yet understand how the C++ files become Ruby code. I could throw together an Ubuntu machine and try it on that I suppose.

Comment: 2 suggestions 1) install [WSL](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) on windows so that a) you can learn a bit about linux; b) you can develop you applications in a linux environment while still utilizing the Windows OS that you undrstand; and 2) you can access the gem on heroku using the heroku [CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) just run `heroku run bash` when that loads up you can view the gems under `vendor/bundle/ruby/[RUBY_VERSION]/gems/[gem name here]`

Comment: Thank you @engineersmnky for the location on Heroku I went into every folder BUT the vendor folder lol.  However once I get into that gem folder and into the lib folder there is m_t_parser.so and it appears to be compiled?  How does Ruby use a Compiled file?  I thought Ruby only parsed un-compiled scripts and it did a JIT for some files that were frequently used at Runtime?  Am I incorrect on this thinking? The src folder has the very same files that I listed above.

Comment: Ruby can load extensions. Per [Kernel#require](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require) Docs: *"If the filename has the extension “.rb”, it is loaded as a source file; if the extension is “.so”, “.o”, or “.dll”, or the default shared library extension on the current platform, Ruby loads the shared library as a Ruby extension. Otherwise, Ruby tries adding “.rb”, “.so”, and so on to the name until found. If the file named cannot be found, a LoadError will be raised."*

Comment: @engineersmnky Do you know the next step in the process how i would use the makefile to make the gem?  I believe that is my next step, I am researching it now.

Comment: Unfortunately we have now reached the end of my knowledge in this instance. While I have utilized extensions, I have never actually created one, C, C++, or otherwise. I think your best best might be to pose a new question revolving solely around how to compile an extension like this and maybe someone with knowledge in that space can assist more appropriately.

Comment: @engineersmnky NP at all, I GREATLY appreciate all your help thus far, I wouldn't have gotten this far if it had not been for you, so thank you very much.  :)